# Using fotorama in vue

Tags: jquery, vue.js, fotorama

I am trying to use Fotorama (photo gallery) in my project on vue-cli. jQuery 3.5.1 and Fotorama installed using NPM. Code part:

```
<script>
    import 'jquery'
    import 'fotorama/fotorama'

    export default {
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Fotorama requires jQuery 1.8 or later and will not run without it.
```

How to make it work?

I was doing:

1. Used jquery and fotorama of the same versions without vue. It works
2. Used the cdn version by adding script tags to the mounted hook
3. Put jquery and fotorama in assets folder. Vue shows me errors in jquery file
4. Added script tags in index.html. It works 50/50. I can’t explain this, but this option works randomly when the page reloads.
5. merged jquery and fotorama into 1 file

Sorry, if there are errors in my question, my English bad. I ask this question 
on the subdomain of my community, but they could not help me. Perhaps there are other libraries that provide such an opportunity. The main thing is that they weigh a little and know how to load pictures when scrolling (not all at once)

Comment: Fotorama's last publish date was 5 years ago. It may require a 1.x or 2.x jQuery version.

Comment: @isherwood No, I tried using the same versions without vue, it works. And 
fotorama is not to blame, this is vue. 
I do not know how this works at a low level, maybe the code when import is executed without using jquery

Comment: I would also agree that there's a conflict with fotorama and the new versions of jQuery. Normally jQuery works fine with vue (and also does in your case) - it's not the vue to blame as it is up-to-date - it's rather this gallery plugin as it hasnt been updated for so long. That's why I would highly recommend using something new as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I changed the title of the question because the problem was not fotorama. This will help find this discussion for those who face the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem.

```
methods {
    // add script tags to head
    loadFotorama() {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js';
        document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
    },
    loadJquery() {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js';
        document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
    }
},
created() {
    this.loadJquery()
},
computed: {
    // this property is true when the server sent links to the desired images
    // images are added to the DOM using v-for
    imagesLoaded() {
        return this.$store.getters.getImagesLoaded
    }
},
watch: {
    imagesLoaded(val) {
        if (val) {
            // while fotorama loads from cdn server vue will create img tags using v-for
            this.loadFotorama()
        }
    } 
}
```

It works fine!
Thanks to everyone who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

The error you get indicates that jQuery might be outdated (it shouldn't happen when downloading via npm though).

You can definitely try to update the package using: `npm update jquery`

Second issue might be the way you import jquery in vue component.

Try this: `import $ from 'jquery';`

You also briefly mentioned that you need a library which weighs a little and loads pictures when scrolling. I would suggest trying [Macy.js](https://github.com/bigbite/macy.js). It is only 4kb so it's much smaller than jQuery itself.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn’t work. Jquery version - 3.5.1

Comment: Does jQuery work when updated and imported in this way? And is the error still there?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just saw the library that you recommended. It does not provide the functionality that I need. In fotorama there is a full-screen mode and it works as a slider. I could not find analogues. This is the only library with such functionality and low weight.